# Location not Updating Using URL variable with Jquery .load()

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I'm using menu links to pass href values jQuery `.load()` to load content into a `div`. For some reason, the load is stuck loading one page and no others. At some point this was working.

Menu links example:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="link1.html" class="load_link">Content 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="link2.html" class="load_link">Content 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="link3.html" class="load_link">Content 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have a `div` with `id="jq_load_content"` where new content will be loaded.

My base script for loading the content into the div is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".load_link").click(function() {


        //TRIED MAKING VARIABLE EMPTY EVERY CLICK
        var contentUrl = null;

        //LOAD VARIABLE WITH HREF ON CLICKED LINK
        var contentUrl = $(this).attr('href');

        // TRIED EMPTYING DIV
        $('#jq_load_content').empty();

        //load url
        $('#jq_load_content').load(contentUrl, function(){
            //Functions after load
         });

        // DISABLE LINK 
        return false;

    }); //End menu link click

}); //End document ready
```

When the links are clicked, only the first href is ever loaded. Initially, even when I click on the other links, `link1.htm` is the content pulled into the `div`.  After I added the `.empty()` function, the others come back blank, but `link1` still works.  All linked files do exist and are properly located. I have even tried testing by call the *same* page only with different query strings (`link1.html?test=1`, `link1.html?test=2`), but still only the first link works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The problem is in `newViewScreen`. What does this hold? Shouldnt this be `contentUrl`

Comment: @Shaunak D yes.  that was a typo in my pasting.  In my actual script I use newViewScreen.  I was trying to simplify naming for the readers.  Thanks.  I have corrected it.

Comment: _"For some reason, the load is stuck loading one page and no others"_  Cannot reproduce

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your JavaScript that would cause the issue you are experiencing. Perhaps you simplified out the problem when creating the question. In debugging your actual code, have you examined the value of the `contentUrl` variable just before `.load()` is called? If you are not familiar with a debugger, you could just add `alert(contentUrl);` at that point.

Comment: You are also declaring `var contentUrl` twice. Remove that. Though this cannot be an issue

Comment: @JohnS  Yes.  I used both div .text for debug and alerts to check on the variable.  Variable shows to have the proper link info.

Comment: @ShaunakD - Yeah.  Just trying everything to make sure the contentUrl variable is clear.

Comment: Post the entire code you are using. The current code seems totally fine.

Comment: @ShaunakD thanks for working with it. the issue was with the secondary load pages.

Answer (score 0):

The above script works as intended.  The error was on the secondary load pages.